# Find the limits $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin (\ln (x^2-x))$

Tags: limits

Find the limits $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin (\ln (x^2-x))$

My Try :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin (\ln (x^2-x))=?\\ \lim_{x\to \infty}\sin (\ln x+\ln(x-1))=\sin \ln x\cos(\ln(x-1))+\cos \ln x \sin (\ln(x-1))$$

Now what ?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Almot1960, I just went through your profile and noticed that you haven't yet accepted an answer on most of the questions you've asked. I'd like to encourage you to accept an answer to your question if it resolves your query, [this is considered good practice on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313042).

Answer (score 5):

The limit does not exist by the following reasoning:
$x^2 - x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. So, $\ln(x^2 - x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. $\sin$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ as its argument tends to infinity. Hence, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(\ln(x^2 - x))$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)= x^2-x, x>1.$

$f : (1,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a continuos ,

increasing, bijective function with

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty.$

Let $y:= f(x)= x^2-x$, $ x>1$, and consider

$F(y):= \sin(\ln(y)).$

Choose :

1)$y_n= e^{2πn}$,  $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

$F(y_n) =0.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(y_n)=0.$

2) $y_n = e^{(π/2 +2πn)}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

$F(y _n) =1.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(y_n) =1.$

The $2$ above sequences converge to different limits. I.e.

the limit does not exist.